# How to derive the curve Ed25519 from Curve25519?

Tags: elliptic-curves, ed25519

According to the paper "Faster addition and doubling on elliptic curves" by Bernstein and Lange, the Montgomery curve (Curve25519) $$v^{2}=u^{3}+486662\cdot u^{2}+u$$ is birationally equivalent to the Edwards curve (Ed25519)
$$x^{2}+y^{2}=1+(121665/121666)\cdot x^{2}y^{2}.$$The paper says that the transformation is easy and can be done with$$v=\sqrt{486662}\cdot u/x$$
$$u=(1+y)/(1-y).$$
However, when I try to do this transformation I do not obtain the Edwards curve, but I get
$$(2+d)x^{2}+dy^{2}=d+(d-2)x^{2}y^{2}$$ with $d=486662$.

So I wonder how, starting from Curve25519, I can get to $e=121665/121666$ and 
$$x^{2}+y^{2}=1+e\cdot x^{2}y^{2}?$$ Thanks!

---

The detailed transformation:

[image: Transformation]

Comment: maybe this helps (somehow): $(d-2)/ 4=121665$ and $(d+2)/4=121666$, meaning $(d-2)/(d+2)=121665/121666$.

Comment: things would work out perfectly if "your" $dy^2$ could be replaced by $(d+2)y^2$ and "your" standalone $d$ by $d+2$... Did you verify your transformations are correct?

Comment: @SEJPM: Thanks for your hints! I checked the transform twice, so I think it is correct. Maybe one has to divide by $d$ and then maybe the birational equivalence allows to replace $x^2$ by $x^2d/(d+2)$? The factor 4 is then just a simplification.

Comment: @SEJPM Seems you´ve got an acceptable answer right there around the corner… ;)

Comment: I think I've just got it. According to [this presentation](https://www.rose-hulman.edu/~brought/Epubs/realelliptic/BirationalEquivalence.pdf) you're allowed to linearly transform the coordinates (and some other things) if you want to keep birational equivalence. So the change you proposed seems to be allowed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First off, your equation is correct and there seems to be no calculation mistake.

To understand on how to get from 
$$(2+d)x^{2}+dy^{2}=d+(d-2)x^{2}y^{2}$$
 to 
$$x^{2}+y^{2}=1+e\cdot x^{2}y^{2}$$
one first needs to observe that $e=(d-2)/(d+2)=121665/121666$ holds.

The next step is to consider:
"What operations are actually *allowed* with birational equivalence?". According to [this presentation](https://www.rose-hulman.edu/~brought/Epubs/realelliptic/BirationalEquivalence.pdf) on a similar topic, linear transformations in the coordinates don't break the birational equivalence as do simple equivalence transformations (the ones having takens us here).

So the substitution $x^2:=x^2\cdot d/(d+2)$ is allowed. If you now perform the substitution, you'll observe 
$$dx^{2}+dy^{2}=d+d(d-2)/(d+2)x^{2}y^{2}$$
and dividing by $d$ yields the desired equation.

Comment: answer 101, I hope it's a good 101 :)

Comment: I have a good feeling with this answer. Thanks again! :)